# Expire time for personal access token in laravel passport module

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I am using laravel for API service for an application. I used personal access token for API access for a user.

```
$token = $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
```

In this function expire time is 1 year and I tried to change the expire time using below code

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
```

I added this code in AuthServiceProvider but its not woking.

Is any other way to add expiration for access token?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation once.

[Laravel Passport Token Expire Time Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#configuration)

and autoload composer and clear cache once.

It may be helpful.

Thanks